# How to summarize column data by nth highest and get date in new df

Tags: r

I have this dataset

```
date<-as.Date(c("2007-01-01","2007-01-02","2007-01-03","2007-01-04","2007-01-05"))
a<-c(55,8,3,7,126)
b<-c(3,199,7,66,8)
c<-c(91,333,2,9,4)
df<-data.frame(date,a,b,c)

  date        a   b   c
 2007-01-01  55   3  91
 2007-01-02   8 199 333
 2007-01-03   3   7   2
 2007-01-04   7  66   9
 2007-01-05 126   8   4
```

I want to 'select' the 2nd highest value from each column (a, b, and c) and get the date of occurrence, and coerce into a new dataframe as below...

```
Type    Date    2nd highest
a    2007-01-01  55
b    2007-01-04  66
c    2007-01-01  91
```

I have tried many different verbs in dplyr, tidyr, apply functions and I really can not even get close.  Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
date<-as.Date(c("2007-01-01","2007-01-02","2007-01-03","2007-01-04","2007-01-05"))
a<-c(55,8,3,7,126)
b<-c(3,199,7,66,8)
c<-c(91,333,2,9,4)
df<-data.frame(date,a,b,c)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(Type,value,-date) %>%  # reshape dataset
  arrange(desc(value)) %>%      # arrange in descending order
  group_by(Type) %>%            # for each type 
  slice(2) %>%                  # get 2nd row (2nd highest value)
  ungroup()                     # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   date       Type  value
#   <date>     <chr> <dbl>
# 1 2007-01-01 a        55
# 2 2007-01-04 b        66
# 3 2007-01-01 c        91
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `nth` (forking AntoniosK's solution):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(Type,value,-date) %>%  # reshape dataset
  group_by(Type) %>%            # for each type 
  filter(value==nth(value,2,-value)) %>%
  ungroup

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# date  Type value
#       <date> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 2007-01-01     a    55
# 2 2007-01-04     b    66
# 3 2007-01-01     c    91
```

And a base R solution:

```
pos  <- sapply(df[-1],function(x) which(rank(-x)==2))
rows <- lapply(1:3,function(x) 
  setNames(transform(df[pos[x],c(1,1+x)],Type=names(pos)[x]),c("date","value","type")))
do.call(rbind,rows)

#          date value type
# 1  2007-01-01    55    a
# 4  2007-01-04    66    b
# 11 2007-01-01    91    c
```

Comment: Wow,  thank you both so very much for your insightful knowledge.